# Finding the first index of a vowel in a given string, otherwise return -1 if there aren't any

Tags: java, string, loops, indexing

So I'm trying to practice writing code by hand for a coding exam, and one of the sample questions is to find the index of the first vowel in a given string, if there are none, return -1.

I tried putting this in eclipse and debugged this. I don't understand why this doesn't work.  I keep getting 101 as an output. Initially I didn't use the index variable, I had the if statement return word.charAt(i). I tried changing that and it didn't do anything.

(For exam purposes, they wanted us to just use lowercase vowels)

Also if you had to write this, what would be an easier way to write this?

```
public static int firstVowel(String word) {
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        int index;

        if (word.charAt(i) == 'a' || word.charAt(i) == 'e' || word.charAt(i) == 'i' || word.charAt(i) == 'o'
                || word.charAt(i) == 'u') {
            index = word.charAt(i);
            return index;
        }
    }

    return -1;

}
```

Comment: String.indexOf would make your code much more readable.

Comment: would I put that in my if statement? I don't think I've used that before.

Comment: No, the code would narrow down to (pseudocode) `min( indexOf('a'), indexOf('e') ... )`. However, such a `min` method is not predefined (`Math.min()` takes only two arguments, which will lead to a heavy nesting of brackets). Thus you have to safeguard `-1` for individual characters, which will lead to most likely more unreadable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the int repesentation of the char, you actually want to return i as this shows the position where you found the char.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are storing word.charAt(i), which returns a character value, into index, which stores an integer.

I believe that when you store a char value in an integer variable that what you're really storing is the ASCII value of the character. 101 represents 'e' on an ASCII table, so what is happening here is that you're detecting an 'e' at index i, and then storing its ASCII value in index and returning index.

To solve your problem, you don't really need the index variable at all. You simply need to return i within your if-statement.